# Pictogram using musical notation

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, rebus

Rebuses: they're music to my eyes.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Forest (four rests)

Comment: It was actually the plural, but the singular'll do.